# Dereference wrapper for vector of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++11, vector, iterator, wrapper, unique-ptr

I recently came across this [article](https://jonasdevlieghere.com/containers-of-unique-pointers/); which provides a basic implementation of boost's `indirect_iterator` but for `unique_ptr` iterators. I decided to tweak the example in the article a little, so that I could use it for vectors outside class members:

```cc
template <typename T>
using SPN = std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>;

template <class BaseIterator>
struct DReferenceIterator : BaseIterator
{
  explicit DReferenceIterator(const BaseIterator & other) : BaseIterator(other) {}
  auto & operator*() const { return *(this->BaseIterator::operator*()); }
  auto * operator->() const { return this->BaseIterator::operator*().get(); }
  auto & operator[](size_t n) const { return *(this->BaseIterator::operator[](n)); }
};

template<typename T>
auto begin_t(std::vector<SPN<T>> & v) 
{
  return DReferenceIterator<typename std::vector<SPN<T>>::iterator>(v.begin());
}

template<typename T>
auto end_t(std::vector<SPN<T>> & v) 
{
  return DReferenceIterator<typename std::vector<SPN<T>>::iterator>(v.end());
}
```

I can use `std::find(begin_t(v), end_t(v), value)` with no problems at all. However, if I try to call `std::sort(begin_t(v), end_t(v))` it does not work at all. I did provide an implemention of `operator<()` in the `Node<T>` class, but for some reason my code does not compile. The compile error that I get is very extensive and hard to read, however, I managed to extract something that I think is causing the problem:

> binary `=`: no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type `std::unique_ptr<Node<float>,std::default_delete<_Ty>>` (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Does this message mean that `std::sort()` is trying to copy `unique_ptr`? In which case, does this mean that the `DReferenceIterator` wrapper does not work as intended? I'm fairly new to C++, so if this is not the case, please help me understand what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `DReferenceIterator` is lying to the standard library as to what it is exposing. This is causing the errors you see trying to `std::sort` through it.

By deriving from `BaseIterator`, you are inheriting the following (among others) `BaseIterator::value_type`, `BaseIterator::pointer` and `BaseIterator::reference`, which don't match the return types of your `operator`s.

A correct implementation would be more like

```
template <class BaseIterator>
struct DReferenceIterator
{
  using value_type = BaseIterator::value_type::element_type;
  using reference = value_type &;
  using pointer = value_type *;
  using difference_type = BaseIterator::difference_type
  using iterator_category = BaseIterator::iterator_category;

  explicit DReferenceIterator(const BaseIterator & other) : other(other) {}

  reference operator*() const { return **other; }
  pointer   operator->() const { return (*other).get(); }
  reference operator[](size_t n) const { return (*other)[n]; }

  DReferenceIterator& operator++() { ++other; return *this; }
  DReferenceIterator& operator--() { --other; return *this; }

  DReferenceIterator& operator+=(difference_type n) { other += n; return *this; }
  DReferenceIterator& operator-=(difference_type n) { other -= n; return *this; }
  difference_type operator-(DReferenceIterator& rhs) { return other - rhs.other; }
  bool operator<(DReferenceIterator& rhs) { return other < rhs.other; }

  // And all the other operators, in terms of those      

private: 
  BaseIterator other;
};
```

Comment: There are no SFINAE friendly requirements on iterators, so you could just add *all* of the operations and rely on the std library not to invoke them, and not being invoked they won't be instantiated.

Comment: @Yakk: Mind explaining how to meet `std::distance` requirements without using SFINAE on operations involving the iterators?  "Since only random access iterators provide `+` and `-` operators, the library provides two function templates `advance` and `distance`. These function templates use `+` and `-` for random access iterators (and are, therefore, constant time for them); for input, forward and bidirectional iterators they use `++` to provide linear time implementations."

Comment: Could you explain, why does `std::find` seems to work?

Comment: @BenVoigt You query the `std::iterator_traits<iterator>::iterator_category  `, and dispatch based on that instead of on if `+` and `-` are defined.  `void print_tag_name( std::random_access_iterator_tag ) { std::cout << "random\n"; }` etc (one *overload* per iterator category tag), then `template<class T> void print_iterator_type() { print_tag_name( typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category{} ); }` has no SFINAE and works for any (compliant) iterator.  Using this to choose between a `++` loop and `+` is left as an exercise.

Comment: @Oli_ver18 The standard places no restrictions on ill-formed programs: it is ill-formed to call std algorithms without proper and accurate iterator categories, but sometimes it still works.  Practically, your standard library's specific implementation of `std::find` didn't need those typedefs to be correct, so it worked.  The sort implementat used those typedefs in a way that broke.  Neither was required to work, and neither was required (by the standard) to fail to compile, or do anything reasonable even.